# Scheduling a command line to call a vbscript using Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, wsh

I may be making this too complicated. Someone else wrote a PowerShell script to reconfigure and activate KMS on W2K8 servers, and it was deployed by SCCM. The key line in his script is:

```
cmd /c $env:systemroot\Sysnative\cscript.exe //Nologo .\slmgr.vbs /skms <newIPAddress> | Out-Host
```

It didn't work on a bunch of systems, and I've been tasked with cleanup.

First, the caveats. Due to Network Security restrictions, I can't remotely call executables on servers, so I can't use Invoke-Command or somesuch. Also, the servers are W2K8, but they only have PS 2.0 on them.

So I got the idea of writing a script to create a scheduled task to run the command. Because of the 2.0 restriction, I'm creating a COM object Schedule.Service, and one of the parameters is the Action, which is where I put the executable, switches, and parameters, all of which will get loaded into the Actions tab in the Scheduled Task.

And that's where I'm stuck. I've tried so many combinations of enclosing portions in quotations, using the explicit path in place of the environment variables (although that will mean it will fail some of the time if the paths are different), and so on.

If I'm looking at this right, I need the Action tab to perform the following:
1. Launch PowerShell
2. Have PowerShell open a command line
3. Have the command line launch cscript
4. Have cscript run slmgr.vbs with the appropriate parameters

Somehow in juggling all those balls, something gets dropped. The closest I can come up with is this:

```
powershell.exe -nologo & 'cmd $env:systemroot\Sysnative\cscript.exe //Nologo .\slmgr.vbs /skms <newIPAddress>'
```

When I manually create a Scheduled Task with that in the Action tab, and then Run it, powershell launches, flashes red to the screen, then closes before I can read it, and the Task reports back "The operation completed successfully". Just for a test, I've also tried:

```
powershell.exe & 'cmd' "cscript slmgr.vbs"
```

That launches PowerShell, which opens a DOS shell, because it won't accept PS commands at that point, but nothing else happens, and the Task reports "The task is currently running"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question, and yes, I was making it too complicated.

First, forget mixing in PowerShell. I'm using PS to create the scheduled tasks, but it's not necessary to use it to call cscript to launch slmgr.vbs. So that's one juggling ball that can be set down.

In the end, when using Schedule.Service to create the tasks, the key factor is Action, and these are the relevant property settings:

```
$TaskService = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$TaskService.Connect($server,$user,$domain,$password)
$NewTask = $TaskService.NewTask(0)
$Action = $NewTask.Actions.Create(0)
$Action.Path = 'cmd'
$Action.Arguments = '/c cscript.exe .\slmgr.vbs /<new IP Address>'
$Action.WorkingDirectory = "%WINDIR%\System32"
```

You'll need to configure the properties for $Settings, the $Triggers, and $Principal, but those are more straightforward.